# How to combine trigger filters in azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a CD pipeline, which uses a CI pipeline as a resource. In my CD pipeline, I have triggers that exclude some project paths that I have in the solution, in my resource I have included my main branch on the trigger.

CD pipeline:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
  paths:
    exclude:
      - src/Customer.Worker.Converter

pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: customer-ci
      source: Customer-API-CI
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - main

stages:
  ...
```

What I want to happen is when I push from my main branch, the CI pipeline runs and activates the CD pipeline only when what I changed is not in the paths I excluded from the trigger, in this case, when I change something in the Customer.Worker.Converter project, I don't want this pipeline to be triggered.

But even when I change something from path Customer.Worker.Converter, the CD pipeline triggers after the CI pipeline, ignoring my exclude path trigger and apparently obeying the CI resource pipeline trigger I use.

Is there any way to get what I want using pipeline resource?

Answer (score 0):

As [per this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops#combining-trigger-types), you've defined two separate triggers, but I think you only want one when the CI pipeline completes. At the moment, you will trigger changes based on the CI pipeline *and* when there are code-pushes.

If you only want the CD pipeline to be triggered when the CI pipeline completes, change the trigger for the CD pipeline to be `none`:

```yaml
# ci pipeline

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    include:
    - src/Customer.Worker.Converter/*

----

# cd pipeline
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: customer-ci
    source: customer-api-ci
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - main # only trigger the CD pipeline when the CI pipeline on 'main' completes.

# do not trigger changes to this pipeline when code-changes are made
trigger: none
```

In theory, you can [combine resource triggers](https://When%20filters%20are%20specified,%20the%20source%20pipeline%20run%20must%20match%20all%20of%20the%20filters%20to%20trigger%20a%20run.):

> When filters are specified, the source pipeline run must match all of the filters to trigger a run.

So one possibility would be to configure the cd pipeline to only run when the CI pipeline completes on the main branch **and** has a specific tag.